# Index of checked/unchecked checkbox in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox, indexing

I am trying to modify XML file based on a value (true/false) of checked checkbox in listview, so I need index of a used checkbox. Problem is whenever I check or uncheck a checkbox I get the same result when using `ListView.FocusedItem.Index` because when clicking on a checkbox item is not selected.

Is it possible to get index of a currently used checkbox in a listview?

Comment: So don't use the `FocusedItem`.  Why would you in the first place?  The `ListView` has a `CheckedIndices` property that gives you the indices of all the checked items and the `ItemCheck` and `ItemChecked` events both provide a reference to the `ListViewItem` that is being or has been checked or unchecked.

Comment: Nothing to look at, hard to answer.  My crystal ball says that you didn't yet notice that you can click a checkbox *without* also changing the selected item.  Note the blue highlight.  If you use the ItemCheck event then be sure to use the e.Item property.  If you use the ItemChecked event then be sure to use the e.Item.Index property.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the ListView ItemCheck event check the e.Index. Here is an example of how I have used this.

```
Private Sub lvCoffee_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles lvCoffee.ItemCheck
        ' e.Current state - the state before the click
        ' e.New State - after the click
        'While the ListView loads the check boxes, keep the update code from running
        If LoadingChecks Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'This code runs BEFORE the check mark changes
        'Hence the use of e.NewValue
        Dim bolFav As Boolean
        If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
            bolFav = True
        Else
            bolFav = False
        End If
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Try
            'I store the primary key value in the Tag property of the ListViewItem
            DataAccess.UpdateFavorites(CInt(lvCoffee.Items(e.Index).Tag), bolFav)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show($"The change to {lvCoffee.Items(e.Index).SubItems(1).Text} failed.{vbCrLf}{ex.Message}", "Favorites change Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Finally
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
        End Try
    End Sub
```